# Unable to send formData to nodejs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms

```
export default funtion Uploader(){

  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const HandleSubmit = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    console.log(file);
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/imageUpdate", formData).then((res) => 
      console.log(res)
    );
  };

  return(
    <form>
      <input
        id="file"
        onChange={changeHandler}
      />
      <button
        onClick={HandleSubmit}
      >
      Update
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(multer().any());

app.post("/imageUpdate", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // '[Object: null prototpye]' if used multer else '{}'
});
```

Here i'm tyring to pass formData from post method which shows empty on server side, I also tried passing `file` in post but it also shows empty. But when I add a manual object as `{random :{ text:'random-text'}}` it shows correctly. Why is that happening ?

Answer (score 0):

hello i think  you need to set a header

```
const config = {


 headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   }
 }
axios.post(url,formData,config)
```

:)

Comment: I tried it, also `application/json`, `multipart/form-data`, but none worked